# How to extract Question/s from document with NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

How to extract Only Question/s from document with NLTK ?

Can we categorise this Question into Y/N and details type answerable ?

**Note**: I am one week old in NLTK ;-)

Comment: Why Question is down vote ?

Answer (score 4):

Check out chapter 6 section 2.2 of the [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html).

EDIT: since apparently the community wants me to copy/paste stuff, here ya go:

---

**2.2   Identifying Dialogue Act Types**

When processing dialogue, it can be useful to think of utterances as a type of action performed by the speaker. This interpretation is most straightforward for performative statements such as "I forgive you" or "I bet you can't climb that hill." But greetings, questions, answers, assertions, and clarifications can all be thought of as types of speech-based actions. Recognizing the dialogue acts underlying the utterances in a dialogue can be an important first step in understanding the conversation.

The NPS Chat Corpus, which was demonstrated in 1, consists of over 10,000 posts from instant messaging sessions. These posts have all been labeled with one of 15 dialogue act types, such as "Statement," "Emotion," "ynQuestion", and "Continuer." We can therefore use this data to build a classifier that can identify the dialogue act types for new instant messaging posts. The first step is to extract the basic messaging data. We will call  xml_posts() to get a data structure representing the XML annotation for each post:

```
>>> posts = nltk.corpus.nps_chat.xml_posts()[:10000]
```

Next, we'll define a simple feature extractor that checks what words the post contains:

```
>>> def dialogue_act_features(post):
...     features = {}
...     for word in nltk.word_tokenize(post):
...         features['contains({})'.format(word.lower())] = True
...     return features
```

Finally, we construct the training and testing data by applying the feature extractor to each post (using  post.get('class') to get a post's dialogue act type), and create a new classifier:

```
>>> featuresets = [(dialogue_act_features(post.text), post.get('class'))
...                for post in posts]
>>> size = int(len(featuresets) * 0.1)
>>> train_set, test_set = featuresets[size:], featuresets[:size]
>>> classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
>>> print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))
0.67
```

Comment: can i add custom training data to this. like i checked with "do i need anaconda for jupyter" then it is showing it as statement.

Comment: I have spent to past 2 days playing with this corpus of data and it has some concerning oddities, like questions tagged as answers and the other way around. In any case, it's mostly teenage MSN chat messages from 2006, so… be careful with it.